# Fixed effects regression with state specific trends

Tags: r, stata

I'm working with panel data and I want to estimate a fixed effects regression with state specific trends.

In Stata, I could accomplish this by the following,

```
xi i.state i.year i.state*time
reg y x _I*
```

The above will create state dummies, year dummies, and 50 (state x time) dummies where time numerically identifies the trend (i.e. 1, 2, 3...)

In R, I can run a fixed effects model with plm or lm, for example,

```
plm(y ~ x, index = c("state", "year"), effect = "twoways", data = df)
 lm(y ~ x + factor(state) + factor(year), data = df)
```

How would I include the 50 (state x time) dummies the way xi does in Stata?

I know `interaction()` is not what I want because that creates a new factor variable with n levels, where n = (num of states) x (num of time periods). What I'm trying to do is create 50 (state x time) variables such that state1xtime is 1,2,3... when state == 1 and zero otherwise, repeat for state2xtime, where state == 2, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `factor(year)`. I think just `lm(y ~ x + factor(state) + year + factor(state):year, data = df)` -- where I'm assuming you're centering your year variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this simply interacting `state` with `year`. The correct operator for this is `:`, which only includes the interactions terms.

Note that there is a subtle difference between `lm` and `plm`:

- for lm, just do `state:year`
- for plm, year has been converted implicitly to a factor, so do `state:as.integer(year)` (doing `state:year` would give you all combinations of state and year).

check:

```
library(plm)

data("Produc", package = "plm")
produc_plm <- pdata.frame(Produc, index = c("state","year"))

### simple state-specific time trend ###
fe1_Ttrend_lm <- lm(log(gsp) ~ -1 + log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp + state +state:year, data = Produc)
fe1_Ttrend_plm <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp + state : as.integer(year), data = produc_plm)

summary(fe1_Ttrend_lm)$coef[1:4,]
summary(fe1_Ttrend_plm)$coef[1:4,]
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete Matifou's answer, you could also do it with the package `fixest`:

```
library(fixest)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
fe_fixest = feols(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp + year::state | state, data = Produc)
# Notice the double colon (on the left the numeric variable, on the right the factor). The alternative also works,
# fe_fixest = feols(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp + interact(year, state) | state, data = Produc)
# fe_fixest = feols(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp + i(year, state) | state, data = Produc)

# Requesting ("standard" standard-errors, otherwise, clustered at state level by default)
coeftable(fe_fixest, se = "standard")[1:4, ]
```

Note that if you don't care about the standard-errors of the interacted coefficients, you can project them out using the following syntax:

```
fe_fixest_bis = feols(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp | state[year], data = Produc)
# state[year] means 'state' fixed-effects and 'state x year' interactions
# The interacted terms are projected out, and the estimation is faster

coeftable(fe_fixest_bis, se = "s")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you are looking for:

```
dta <- data.frame(state = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10), 
              time = rep(1:3, each = 10))
dta <- cbind(dta, model.matrix( ~ state - 1, data = dta) * dta$time)

head(dta, 1)
#     state time stateA stateB stateC
# 1     A    1      1      0      0

tail(dta, 1)
#      state time stateA stateB stateC
# 30     C    3      0      0      3
```

Comment: There might be better way but this solution works with the following modification,

Comment: `dta <- data.frame(state = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10), time  = rep(seq(1, 10, 1), each = 3))`